# Upper bound on distance between minimizers of two convex objective functions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Assume we have two convex objective functions, $f$ and $\tilde{f}$, where

$$ f(x) \leq \tilde{f}(x), \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d$$

Let

$$\begin{aligned} x^* &:= \arg\min_{x} f(x)\\ \tilde{x}^* &:= \arg\min_{x} \tilde{f}(x)\end{aligned}$$

How to obtain an upper bound for $\| x^*-\tilde{x}^* \|$?

I think that this problem is way too general. But is there any paper, or method which suggest a method for a problem of this type?

Comment: Such an upper bound does not exist in general. Are you asking for additional conditions that potentially do ensure such a result exists?

Comment: @Marc, Yes. and if there is an example that one found this upper bound for a problem.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, what do you mean by quantifiers?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, yes. Thank you.